# Как открыть gwt designer в eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

Установил плагин для eclipse - gwt eclipse plugin 3.0.0
когда нажимаю правой кнопкой мыши на соответствующий класс или на `ui.xml` там дизайнера не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

С версии [2.7](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_7_0_RC1) `gwt designer` больше не поддерживается